# How to update or remove all special characters from a varchar column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, special-characters

I've messed around and allow users to create company names to where they're creating company names like so: Tom & Marks Ice Cream Shop.

The problem is that the company name has a link for others to click on the see the company's profile and  .net is throwing a error stating that dangerous characters are not allowed.

I'm not worried about being to precise with the company name the user can update it their self when every they notice that the '&' is gone.

How can I update a column in SQL with SQL syntax to where all the special characters are removed and a space is added in the place of the special character?

Is there a way to identify in sql if there is a special character in a column value?

```
UPDATE [BuildingPros].[utbProfessionals]
   SET [ProfessionalName] = Replace([ProfessionalName],'some character',' ')
 WHERE ProfessionalName =ProfessionalName
```

Comment: I would fix the underlying  *dangerous characters are not allowed.* issue (you should describe this) rather than change the data. If handled correctly you should not experience problems

Comment: I will put that statement in the areas where the user creates their company name for the first time and where they update their name, but for now, I need to fix the boo boo.

Comment: @AlexK.'s point was that the database should allow whatever characters the user wants.  Any filtering of "bad characters" should be done (in software) when you read the values out of the DB.

Comment: I know this. It has nothing to do with the DB it has everything to do when a see profile link is clicked and there is a '&' in the url.

Comment: I know this. It has nothing to do with the DB it has everything to do when a see profile link is clicked and there is a '&' in the url. The server doesn't like urls with special characters. I know I can make it work, but I do not want to go that route, I would rather there be no special characters in the url.

Answer (score 5):

This is the sample code to find string contains special character or not. You can try this one

```
DECLARE @MyString VARCHAR(100)
SET @MyString = 'abcdef&&&&ybyds'

IF (@MyString LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%')
    BEGIN
       SET @MyString = Replace(@MyString,'&',' ')
       PRINT 'Contains "special" characters'
       PRINT @MyString
  END
ELSE
    BEGIN
       PRINT 'Does not contain "special" characters'
       PRINT @MyString
    END
```

And your UPDATE query will be like this:-

```
UPDATE [BuildingPros].[utbProfessionals]
SET [ProfessionalName] = 
                        (
                         CASE 
                            WHEN [ProfessionalName] LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%' 
                                  THEN Replace(REPLACE( ProfessionalName, SUBSTRING( ProfessionalName, PATINDEX('%[~,@,#,$,%,&,*,^,&,%,*,(,)]%', ProfessionalName), 1 ),''),'-',' ')
                            ELSE [ProfessionalName]
                          END
                         )
```

Or You can create a function to remove special char function then call it under Update statement.

1) Removes special characters from a string value.
2) All characters except 0-9, a-z and A-Z are removed and
3) the remaining characters are returned.

```
 create function dbo.RemoveSpecialChars (@s varchar(256)) returns varchar(256)
       with schemabinding
    begin
       if @s is null
          return null
       declare @s2 varchar(256)
       set @s2 = ''
       declare @l int
       set @l = len(@s)
       declare @p int
       set @p = 1
       while @p <= @l begin
          declare @c int
          set @c = ascii(substring(@s, @p, 1))
          if @c between 48 and 57 or @c between 65 and 90 or @c between 97 and 122
             set @s2 = @s2 + char(@c)
          set @p = @p + 1
          end
       if len(@s2) = 0
          return null
       return @s2
       end
```

then call this function in update statement:-

```
UPDATE [BuildingPros].[utbProfessionals]
SET [ProfessionalName] = 
                   (
                     CASE 
                      WHEN [ProfessionalName] LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%' 
                           THEN (SELECT dbo.RemoveSpecialChars(ProfessionalName))
                      ELSE [ProfessionalName]
                      END
                    )
```

[Refer](http://www.source-code.biz/snippets/mssql/1.htm)

Comment: This is only for the '&', I need it for any special character.

Comment: see modified answer, you can include any special char in here